# Java implementation of bitwise division

Tags: java, binary, bit

```
    String n1="1010100000000010",n2="10000111";
    int div=Integer.parseInt(n1,2);
    int divisor=Integer.parseInt(n2,2);
    int div_Hi=0;

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){

        dividend<<=1;

        if(dividend_Hi>=divisor){

            dividend_Hi-=divisor;
            dividend=dividend+1;

        }
    }
```

In the picture,there is an algorithm for binary division. Following are my questions regarding it:

- How do I initialize dividend_Hi?
- How do I use dividend_Lo in the code?
- What corrections do I need to make in the code?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dividend_Hi` is simply the upper half of your 2n-bit dividend. So let's assume your dividend is 6 (110) and divisor is 2 (10). `n` in this case would be 3 because that's the minimum number of bits you'll need to represent your integers. So for a 2n-bit dividend (2n = 6), you simply pad out the left with zeros (000110).

```
int dividend = 6;
int divisor  = 2;
int n1 = Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(dividend);
int n2 = Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(divisor);
int n = n1 >= n2 ? n1 : n2;
int dividend_Hi = dividend >> n;
int dividend_Lo = dividend & ((1 << n) - 1);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dividend <<= 1;
    dividend_Hi = dividend >> n;
    if (dividend_Hi >= divisor) {
        dividend_Hi -= divisor;
        dividend++;
    }
    dividend_Lo = dividend & ((1 << n) - 1);
    dividend = dividend_Hi << n | dividend_Lo;
}
```

Comment: If i am taking dividend=8, then dividend_Lo's value=1, shouldn't it be 4? @DrazenBjelovuk

Comment: Thanks now I understand @DrazenBjelovuk

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `n` is 4, and you want high 4 bits and low 4 bits of the 8-bit number:

```
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
   ↓       ↓
   ↓    0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

Simply keeping the low `n` bit is easy enough, you just mask out the rest. In bit-logic that would means a bit-wise AND with `00001111`, which you can calculate by shifting `1` left by `n`, getting `10000`, then subtracting `1`, giving you `1111`.

```
lo = num & ((1 << n) - 1);
```

Getting the high bits is even easier. Just shift `n` bits to the right:

```
hi = num >>> n;
```